# PHP Array index value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple question that needs to get an element when selecting that reference ID by an input form. I used the following code to do that.

```
$id2=$locationProducts[0]->inventory_update_stock_details_id;
```

But this code outs only the first element always. AS an exmple inventory_update_stock_details_id=36, inventory_update_stock_details_id=36, inventory_update_stock_details_id=36 and so on.

But I needs to select as inventory_update_stock_details_id=35, inventory_update_stock_details_id=345, inventory_update_stock_details_id=2 like that.

inventory_update_stock_details_id included ids as 1,2,3,4,5,......1000

The model as follows :

```
function getInventoryLocationProducts()
    {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from('store_inventory_update_stock_details');
        $this->db->join('store_inventory_item', 'store_inventory_item.inventory_item_id=store_inventory_update_stock_details.inventory','left');
        $this->db->join('store_inventory_location_update', 'store_inventory_location_update.inventory_update_stock_id=store_inventory_update_stock_details.inventory_update_stock_id','left');
        $this->db->join('store_inventory_update_stock', 'store_inventory_update_stock.inventory_update_stock_id=store_inventory_location_update.inventory_update_stock_id','left');
        $this->db->where('store_inventory_item.status=1');
        $this->db->where('store_inventory_update_stock_details.serial_no NOT IN (select serial_no from store_inventory_location_update)');
        
        $q = $this->db->get_where();
        
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $q->result();
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
```

## Controller

```
public function addInventoryLocation()
{
    $this->checkPermissions('add', 'inventoryLocation');
    $bc = array(array('link' => '#', 'page' => 'Inventory Locations'));
    $meta = array('page_title' => 'Inventory Locations', 'bc' => $bc);
    $this->data['branch'] = $this->Item_model->getBranch();
    $this->data['office'] = $this->Item_model->getOffice();
    $locationProducts = $this->Item_model->getInventoryLocationProducts();
    $this->data['locationProducts'] = $locationProducts;

    $this->data['auto_loc_no'] = $this->Item_model->generate_inv_loc_ref();

    $count = $this->input->post('i');
    
    $str = $this->input->post('auto_loc_no');
    $auto_loc = preg_replace("/[^0-9]{1,4}/", '', $str);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('branch', 'Branch', 'required');
            
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
        
        $stock = array(
            
            'office_id' => $this->input->post('office'),
            'branch' => $this->input->post('branch'),
            'l_date' => $this->input->post('l_date'),
            'is_order_no' => $this->input->post('is_order_no'),               
            'loc_no' => $this->input->post('auto_loc_no'),
            'auto_loc_no' => $auto_loc,           
            'user' => ucfirst($this->session->userdata('name')),
            'order_status' => 'locate',
            'status' => 1
        );
        $id = $this->Item_model->addInventoryLocation($stock);
        
                   
    }
    $id2=$locationProducts[0]->inventory_update_stock_details_id;       
    dd($id2);

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $id2 != 0) {
            $count = $this->input->post('i');
            for ($x = 0; $x <= $count; $x++) {
                $details[$x]['inventory_update_stock_id'] = $id2;                    
                $details[$x]['inventory'] = $this->input->post('inventory' . $x);                   
                $details[$x]['serial_no'] = $this->input->post('serial_no' . $x);
                $details[$x]['item_code'] = $this->input->post('item_code' . $x);
                $details[$x]['officer'] = $this->input->post('officer' . $x);
                $details[$x]['qty'] = 1;                    
                $details[$x]['status'] = 1;
                $details[$x]['branch'] = $this->input->post('branch');
            }

        if ($this->Item_model->addInventoryLocationDetails($details)) {
            echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>"); 
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Successfully Added ..!!');                              
            redirect('item/addInventoryLocation');
        }
    } else {
        
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', validation_errors());
        $this->render('item/addInventoryLocation', $meta, $this->data);
    }

}
```

## View

```
<td style="width: 30%">
                                <input type="hidden" name="i" id="i" value="0">
                                <select name="inventory0" id="inventory0" class="form-control select2 inventory-select" required>
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <?php
                                    if (!empty($locationProducts)) {
                                        foreach ($locationProducts as $row) {
                                                echo "<option value='".$row->inventory_update_stock_details_id."'> $row->inventory_update_stock_details_id - $row->inventory_item_name</option>";
                                            ?>
                                            
                                           
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    }

                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </td>
```

What can modify my code line to do that. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Are there more than 1 elements?

Comment: @ 
Honk der Hase. Yes

Comment: The `[0]` part is telling PHP you want the first element. If there are multiple, make that part dynamic, for example `[$next]`. Or use a loop if you want them all.

Comment: @ 
rickdenhaan. Can you modify the code as per your sugesstion ?

Comment: No, because you haven't actually shared your code. That is to say, I would need more information about the context that single line of code is executed in. Is it already in a loop? How do you know which item you want at that particular place?

Comment: @  
rickdenhaan. I can share the code in my model

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't appear to be where that line of code is. Can you share the code before and after that line where `$id2` is defined?

Comment: "Can you modify the code as per your sugesstion"  Stackoverflow is not a code writing/modifying service....  You should change the code yourself after the input given here...

Comment: @ rickdenhaan. I added the relevant code part in my controller too.

Comment: No, you haven't. I still have no idea where that `$id2=$locationProducts[0]->inventory_update_stock_details_id;` line is in relation to the code fragments you've posted. Can you literally copy/paste that specific line plus, for example, the 5 lines of code before and after it?

Comment: @  
rickdenhaan. Ok. I Added the whole code in my controller. Due to the lenght of code, I wasn't added all the codes in earlier.

Comment: @ rickdenhaan.. Pls. ignore the other methods in my controller except getInventoryLocationProducts() at this moment

Comment: You've got the code you need already there in your view: `foreach ($locationProducts as $row) {`. What's stopping you using that same code in your controller?

Comment: @ 
IMSoP. Yes. the code is working fine. But I need to insert inventory_update_stock_details_id into another table as hidden value, when performing this operation. So, I want to select the relevant ID internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the intended logic is, but I ***think*** what you want is to add the InventoryLocationDetails to all InventoryLocationProducts.

If that is correct, you could perhaps do something like this:

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
        $details = [];

        foreach ($locationProducts as $locationProduct) {
            $id2 = $locationProduct->inventory_update_stock_details_id;

            $count = $this->input->post('i');
            for ($x = 0; $x <= $count; $x++) {
                $details[] = [
                    'inventory_update_stock_id' => $id2,
                    'inventory' => $this->input->post('inventory' . $x),
                    'serial_no' => $this->input->post('serial_no' . $x),
                    'item_code' => $this->input->post('item_code' . $x),
                    'officer' => $this->input->post('officer' . $x);
                    'qty' => 1,
                    'status' => 1,
                    'branch' => $this->input->post('branch'),
                ];
            }
        }

        if ($this->Item_model->addInventoryLocationDetails($details)) {
            echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>"); 
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Successfully Added ..!!');                              
            redirect('item/addInventoryLocation');
        }
    }
```

This assumes that `$locationProducts` contains only those products that actually need to be updated. If you need to only update some of them, you can add the logic to determine which product to update inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @ rickdenhaan. You are correct. But got the same result. The same id outs repeatedly, even select different items.

Comment: @ rickdenhaan. I am selecting only one item at a time using my view. Not to all InventoryLocationProducts at a time. So, needs to select one inventory_update_stock_details_id at a time internally to be inserted into the location_update_table. If I say in other words, that I needs to select item id (inventory_update_stock_details_id) from the item table as per form selecting of item to be inserted into location_update_table. (Left Join will be arranged)

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to follow, but it sounds like `$id2` is actually the same as `$this->input->post('inventory' . $x)` then, isn't it? Because the value chosen there already came from `inventory_update_stock_details_id`.

Comment: @
rickdenhaan. Yes. That is.